# upload image file security using imagecreate, imagejpeg

Tags: php

I have a input type file for user to upload image jpeg only

I have check all MIME, getimagesize, exif_imagetype.

after that I user, imagecreatetruecolor, imagecreatefromjpeg... to crop the image (user can draggable image).

My question is after I use imagecreatetruecolor, imagecreatefromjpeg... those function.

(I have set up my own size, so all image will be the same size)

Will this format the file into jpeg for security?

ex. if user upload the file like sample.exe.jpg or sample.jpg(php, or js file)

```
$dst_image=imagecreatetruecolor($dst_w, $dst_h);
$src_image=imagecreatefromjpeg('testing.jpg');

imagecopyresampled($dst_image, $src_image, $dst_x, $dst_y, $src_x, $src_y, $dst_w, $dst_h, $src_w, $src_h);
imagejpeg($dst_image, 'random_name.jpg');
```

Comment: "for security" What security? security isn't something you sprinkle onto code like salt on food...

Comment: The resized and re-encoded image will virtually almost certainly (yeah, you can never say "100%" ;)) not contain anything that may exploit parsing flaws in image processors, if that's what you mean. But I'm not sure whether you're asking this.

Comment: ya that is what im asking, thx a lot!